# Is there a way of automatically generating a code map

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, flowchart

Apologies if the answer to this is obvious.

Is there a way in c# and visual studio to analyse the code and automatically generate a flow chart of the sequence of events or put it another way, a tool that can document the stack?

Seems like it must have been thought of or asked many times before but I haven’t found an answer much less a tool that will do it.